# Deleting a doublepointer (matrix)

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation, new-operator

I am solving a quantum-mech problem which requires me to find some eigenvalues by manipulating some matrices. The specifics of this problem is not relevant, I just need help with the c++ problem, I am new to this language and after a couple of hours I figured any more attempts at solving it myself would be futile and so I turn to you for help.

I have this problem where glibc detects an error at the end of my program and I cannot deallocate properly, it is far too big to copypaste here so I will just replicate the part that actually gives the error.

```
void hamiltonian(int, double **&);

int i,j;

int main()
{
int N = 1000; double **A;

hamiltonian(N, A);

//Physics here
.
.
.
.
.
//Delete
for(i=0; i<N; i++){delete []A[i];}
delete []A;

return 0;
}

void hamiltonian(int N, double **&A)
{
A = new double *[N];
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
A[i] = new double[N];
for(j=0; j<N; j++)
{
if(i==j)A[i][j] = 2;
if(i==j+1 || i==j-1){A[i][j] = 1;}
}
}
}
```

According to my professor I have to deallocate in the same function as I allocate but I didn't even think about deallocation after being nearly done with my project and so I have to rewrite a lot of code, the problem is that I cannot deallocate A inside the hamiltonian function as I need it in other functions (inside //Physics).

Surely there must be a way around this? Might sound a bit ignorant of me but this sounds like a less efficient design if I have to deallocate in the same function as I allocate.

Comment: Edited to add delete[A] and A[i] = new double[N];

Comment: Implementing own matrix functionality is probably OK for studying C++, but if your main goal is quantum-mech problem, isn't it better to find an existing library able to operate on matrices and work with eigenvalues?

Comment: @maxim1000 Yes but it is not as much fun :p

Comment: in that case I would advice to develop a class Matrix which is convenient to use (hides memory management and internal details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to my professor I have to deallocate in the same function as I allocate

That is pure silliness. Sometimes (almost always) you need to use the allocated struct outside the function. Definitely false for objects, since constructors and destructors are different functions.

Any way, you can get away without using classes, if you make a Matrix `struct` and associated `newMatrix` and `deleteMatrix` functions :)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Matrix
{
    int n;
    int m;
    double** v;
};

Matrix newMatrix (int n, int m)
{
    Matrix A;
    A.n = n;
    A.m = m;
    A.v = new double*[n];
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        A.v[i] = new double[m];
    }
    return A;
}

Matrix newHamiltonianMatrix (int n, int m)
{
    Matrix A = newMatrix(n, m);
    for( int i = 0; i < A.n; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < A.m; j++ ){
            A.v[i][j] = 0.0;
            if( i == j ){
                A.v[i][j] = 2.0;
            }
            if( i == j + 1 or i == j - 1 ){
                A.v[i][j] = 1.0;
            }
        }
    }
    return A;
}

void deleteMatrix (Matrix A)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < A.n; i++ ){
        delete [] A.v[i];
    }
    delete [] A.v;
    A.v = NULL;
}

int main ()
{
    Matrix A = newHamiltonianMatrix(10, 20);
    for( int i = 0; i < A.n; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < A.m; j++ ){
            cout << A.v[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    deleteMatrix(A);
}
```

Comment: Would setting A = null in my original code work as a crude delete? Will A instead of occuping NxN doubles just become a 0 pointer?

Comment: No, that doesn't delete the allocated double[] and double[][] arrays. C++ does not use garbage collection (well, there are third party GC libraries but that's another topic)

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion will save me the trouble of rewriting my whole code and I will gladly accept this as an answer to my problem but hoping someone will expand on why glibc doesn't like me deleting my matrix. I think my professor meant that I have to delete it in hamiltonian since glibc gave me an error, he meant this specifically and not in general about deleting pointers. I don't understand the logic of delete not working outside the hamiltonian function.

Comment: +1, "That is pure silliness." This sounds very much like a prof who takes too much guidance from Numerical Recipes in C, where this silliness is extremely pervasive.

Comment: @user948652 No idea, it works perfectly here, and I do not see any problem with it either. Perhaps you are running an old version of your code?

Comment: @David Hammen: No his professor is correct. It is just badly worded translation of what the professor would have said that has been over generalized. Allocation/Deallocation code should be localized so that they are close to each other (this is why in C++ constructor/destructor are paired). Either do this with two methods located together or put the code in one function. keeping the code symetric like this will led to less bugs as you do not hunt for the allocation/deallocation pair.

Comment: @Tux-D: One word: Factory. Factories are but one of many examples of widely separated allocation and deallocation, widely separated both in terms of where in the code and in terms of when in the course of execution.

Comment: @David Hammen: Two word. So what. We use constructors/destructors to localise the resource allocation into a single place. Your advice is over generalized. Then the rest is done by smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete A;
```

Needs to be

```
delete[] A;
```

If you `new[]` it, you MUST `delete[]` it. Also, use a `vector`- they take care of themselves.

```
vector<vector<double>> matrix;
```

Comment: Yes of course, I forgot the [] in the above code, it is in my original. We are not supposed to use/construct classes yet, this is a class in computational physics (mostly about algorithms to different problems and their implementation, in which c++ was decided upon a vote).

Comment: @user948652: If you want to write C++, you *must* use classes. It is not an option. Whoever decided to try to teach you allocation without using classes is a moron, and you should shoot them, and then use classes anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG: Unless I missed some rule in the standard that disallows the use of primitive types, arrays of primitive types, your statement that "*If you want to write C++, you **must** use classes. It is not an option.*" is nonsense.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Sure, if you want your code to be hideously buggy and unreliable, no exception safety, etc etc. Technically, you *could* write C++ without them, but in reality, it's not an option.

Comment: We are learning classes, next week. Semester started 4 weeks ago.

Comment: @David Hammen: I am with DeadMG here. Not using classes is just writting C code and pretending it is C++. The above is not C++ it is C they just happen to be using a C++ compiler (and new rather than malloc). Writting correct C++ has a lot to do about the style that is used. There should be no pointers there should be no need to actually call delete (basically it is all wrong for C++ code).

Comment: @Tux-D: Did you see the comment from one hour before yours? *We are learning classes, next week. Semester started 4 weeks ago.* Did you see the first comment: *This is a class in computational physics*? Classes are of secondary importance here. Learning how to invert a matrix, compute a Hamiltonian, solve a set of ordinary or partial differential equations, deal with the vagaries of how computers represent numbers are of much greater importance. Now that they've made a start at these greater concerns they can start addressing language-specific concepts such as classes.

Comment: @David Hammen: None of that is relevant. It does not change C into being C++. DeadMG original comment still holds true. You are now just trolling.

Comment: @Tux-D: Trolling? The trolling started with DeadMG. user948652's course is just about on par for a computational physics / numerical programming class. Since you accused me of trolling, now I will: I like the power of C++, but that class couldn't have voted for a worse language (the class chose C++). C++ has too much learning overhead when it comes to an introductory language for computational physics, or any numerical programming class. Matlab, python, most any functional language, heck, even Fortran would have been a better choice.

Comment: @David Hammen: As expected none of that is relevant to a question tagged as C++/dynamic-allocation. Maybe a more appropriate pace for your rant is your professors blog comments. But I am willing to bet your over simplistic generalizations would get shot down just as quickly there.

Comment: @Tux-D: Oh please. The kid is *just* learning computational physics. It is very likely this is the first experience in programming for many of these students. You are treating the questioner as you would a comp sci major who has already taken at least one course in C++. The sole trolling here (other than my intentional one) is yours and DeadMG's. Science and engineering students oftentimes no longer have to take the intro computer science class (an unfortunate development, IMO). Look at things from this perspective.

Comment: @David Hammen: It has been **only** you since the beginning. Each of your posts has become increasingly less relevant to the topic. Time to grow up.

Comment: This is way out of hand. The fault lies with the professor who would teach dynamic allocation without teaching classes. The fact is that classes are a very, very basic part of C++, and their use is basically necessitated for all programs which need to manage dynamic resources, including memory, and the Standard provides a perfectly good class for doing this, `vector`. The course he's on and his previous experience are irrelevant to this simple fact.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with your code.

**(1)** You are **not allocating** memory to the pointer members of `A`. i.e. `A[i]` are not allocated with `new[]`. So accessing them is an **undefined behavior**.

**(2)** You must do `delete[]` for a pointer if it was allocated with `new[]`. In your other function `delete A;` is wrong. Use `delete[] A;`

**(3)** Using `new/new[]` is not the only way of allocation. In fact you should use such dynamic allocation when there is no choice left. From your code it seems that you are hard coding `N=1000`. So it's better to use an 2D array.

```
const int N = 1000;  // globally visible
int main ()
{
  double A[N][N];
  ...
}
void hamiltonian (double (&A)[N][N])
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Lastly, the idea that, "you have to deallocate in the same function as you allocated" is utter nonsense.

Comment: In retrospect it might be wiser to just copypaste the whole 600 lines, I made another mistake (the file is in my linux, I am on windows). I do of course allocate A[i] = new double[N]; inside the loop. As to point 2, also another mistake, if you check my comment to the previous poster. N is also an input variable but for the sake of simplifying my problem here I just set it as a constant.

Comment: -1 for a local variable `double A[N][N];` with N=1000? Seriously? The result is the name of this website.

Comment: @DavidHammen, I don't know why **down voted**. Why do you see stackoverflow happening  here ? `double[1000 * 1000]` can be [allocated on stack](http://www.ideone.com/vFr3l). That is a different situation that OP may not want to do it as the requirements are dynamic. But one can not down vote for that !!!

Comment: Yes, I can, and I did. The default stack size on many machines is about 8 meg, barely enough to hold that array. He may want to compute the inverse of that matrix, or perform an eigen decomposition, and with an 8 meg limit, there isn't room for two or three such arrays. Oftentimes sys admins will limit non-superusers to a considerably smaller stack size limit. It is not a good idea to allocate that big of an array on the stack.